# Finding the inverse of $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1x_2, x_1^2-x_2^2)$

Tags: calculus

As the title suggests, I'm having some difficulty finding the inverse of this function for my advanced calculus class. The question asks us to explicitly find the inverse of $f(x_1,x_2)=(x_1x_2, x_1^2-x_2^2)$ for $f:\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^2|x_1>0,x_2>0\rbrace\rightarrow\lbrace y\in\mathbb{R}^2|y_1>0\rbrace$

So far I have converted the equation to a polar form $f(r,\theta)=(\frac{1}{2}r^2sin2\theta, r^2cos2\theta)$ where $f:(0,\infty)\times[0,2\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\smallsetminus\lbrace0\rbrace$, then a bit more work got me to $(4y_1^2+y_2^2)^{1/4}=r$, and so $f^{-1}(y_1,y_2)=((4y_1^2+y_2^2)^{1/4},?)$. This is where I am now stuck, as ? needs to be some function to get $\theta$ from $(y_1,y_2)$, and this quickly turns into a mess of variables.

I'm not looking for an answer so much as a process that may or may not be easier or a hint; I missed a lecture and I worry that I missed something important to this problem.

For context, we have been working with the Inverse Function and Implicit Function Theorems lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**$$ \frac{2y_1}{y_2} = \tan(2\theta)$$

Comment: Ah, that did it. Thanks!